# Celery worker not executing task properly(tasks are being received from beat)

Tags: redis, scheduled-tasks, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I am trying to add celery-redis combo to my django project. Installed celery, django-celery-beat and made other set ups. I wrote a simple task to sent me a message in telegram(added logger.info at the beginning, telegram messages work fine wihout scheduling):

```
import logging

from celery import shared_task
from borrowings.telegram_helpers import send_telegram_notification

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@shared_task
def send_hi():
    logger.info("Sending hi!")
    message = "Hi!"
    send_telegram_notification(message)
```

then i launch redis from cmd terminal
`D:\Redis>redis-server.exe`
Then i launch worker
`LibraryService worker -l info`
And finally i launch beat:
`celery -A LibraryService beat -l info`

The task is set to be executed every minute(in settings.py)

That is what i see in beat logs:

```
2023-07-31 02:51:14,974 [INFO] beat: Starting...
2023-07-31 02:51:15,001 [INFO] Scheduler: Sending due task send_hi (borrowings.tasks.send_hi)
2023-07-31 02:52:14,997 [INFO] Scheduler: Sending due task send_hi (borrowings.tasks.send_hi)
2023-07-31 02:53:14,998 [INFO] Scheduler: Sending due task send_hi (borrowings.tasks.send_hi)
2023-07-31 02:54:14,998 [INFO] Scheduler: Sending due task send_hi (borrowings.tasks.send_hi)
2023-07-31 02:55:14,999 [INFO] Scheduler: Sending due task send_hi (borrowings.tasks.send_hi)
2023-07-31 02:56:14,999 [INFO] Scheduler: Sending due task send_hi (borrowings.tasks.send_hi)
```

That is what i see in worker logs:

```
2023-07-31 02:51:04,640 [INFO] mingle: searching for neighbors
2023-07-31 02:51:05,176 [INFO] child process 20816 calling self.run()
2023-07-31 02:51:05,278 [INFO] child process 1748 calling self.run()
2023-07-31 02:51:05,284 [INFO] child process 21456 calling self.run()
2023-07-31 02:51:05,325 [INFO] child process 19108 calling self.run()
2023-07-31 02:51:05,338 [INFO] child process 23508 calling self.run()
2023-07-31 02:51:05,345 [INFO] child process 22716 calling self.run()
2023-07-31 02:51:05,398 [INFO] child process 18304 calling self.run()
2023-07-31 02:51:05,428 [INFO] child process 20284 calling self.run()
2023-07-31 02:51:05,668 [WARNING] D:\projects\django\LibraryService\venv\Lib\site-packages\celery\app\control.py:56: DuplicateNodenameWarning: Received multiple replies from node name: celery@Dmytry.
2023-07-31 02:54:15,000 [INFO] Task borrowings.tasks.send_hi[e752e4ec-cfbe-49a8-8af3-81baef67845e] received
2023-07-31 02:54:15,842 [INFO] child process 21376 calling self.run()
2023-07-31 02:54:15,842 [INFO] child process 1416 calling self.run()
2023-07-31 02:54:15,842 [INFO] child process 1468 calling self.run()
2023-07-31 02:54:15,844 [INFO] child process 1204 calling self.run()
2023-07-31 02:54:15,854 [INFO] child process 21108 calling self.run()
2023-07-31 02:56:15,001 [INFO] Task borrowings.tasks.send_hi[87dfe9ca-efbb-4349-81de-52ae60bb84e2] received
2023-07-31 02:56:15,855 [INFO] child process 12220 calling self.run()
```

I tried to add log message, but nothing changed and no message in terminal appeared